# Excel macro to save sheets as new macro enabled workbook

Tags: vba, excel

So far I have this:

```
Sub new_book()

    Sheets(Array("Document Data", "Invoice data", "Summary", "Invoice")).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("D1") & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=52

End Sub
```

However I get runtime error 1004, which highlights the ActiveWorkbook line. What exactly is wrong? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) is using the correct *FileFormat* parameter ([xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) = 52) but you are inexplicably trying to append the filename with a hard-coded .xlsx file extension rather than an .xlsm file extension. In any event, the correct extension will be added if you do not supply it.

```
Sub new_book()

    Sheets(Array("Document Data", "Invoice data", "Summary", "Invoice")).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("D1") & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") , FileFormat:=52

End Sub
```

I'm a little uncomfortable with the use of `Range("D1")` without specifying a parent worksheet. Be very careful about not attempting to use restricted characters in the filename.

Comment: Thank you! Range("'Sheet1'!D1") gives me an error, so how should I go about formatting it?

Comment: Try as `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1")`

Comment: As Nicholas has pointed out, you should always explicitly specify the parent worksheet. You are already using the `ActiveWorkbook` from the newly created workbook with the copied worksheets. If the name you want is in D4 on the 'Document Data' worksheet, you would use `Sheets("Document Data").Range("D4")`.

Answer (score 3):

Try as follow:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("D1") & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy"), FileFormat:=52
```

Answer (score -1):

"SAVING FILE WITH TODAYS DATE AS NAME IN "D:\BACKUP" folder

```
sub new_sheet()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\BACKUP")

todays_date = Date$

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

 If objFile.Name = todays_date & ".xls" Then
    objFile.Delete

 End If

 Next objFile



Workbooks.Add

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\BACKUP" & todays_date & ".xls"    
end sub
```